# putty -> tmux -> vim -> change cursor shape

Tags: vim, putty, tmux

When I use vim in putty I change my cursor in insert mode.

These are my settings:

*putty:*

- cursor appearance: vertical line
- terminal: xterm-256color

*.zshrc*
added this the get a block cursor on login:

> echo -en "\e[=2c"

*.vimrc*

> " Insert Mode -> normal cursor (line)
>   let &t_SI .= "\e[=1c"
>   " Normal Mode -> block cursor
>   let &t_EI .= "\e[=2c"

This works, but it doesn't when I use vim inside tmux.

I use this in my .tmux.conf:

> set -g default-terminal "xterm-256color"

Here are my complete dotfiles: https://github.com/r03/dotfiles

Any idea how I can use the putty escape code in tmux?

This command should change my cursor inside tmux:

> echo -en "\e[=1c"
>   echo -en "\e[=2c"

Comment: You might want to check out the [Vi and Vim Stack Exchange](https://vi.stackexchange.com/) for questions on Vim!

Answer (score 1):

The solution is this in .vimrc:

```
if exists('$TMUX')
    let &t_SI .= "\ePtmux;\e\e[=1c\e\\"
    let &t_EI .= "\ePtmux;\e\e[=2c\e\\"
 else
    let &t_SI .= "\e[=1c"
    let &t_EI .= "\e[=2c"
 endif
```